# Django - can you use the on_delete attribute on a OnetoOneField?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In the docs it only specifies an `on_delete` attribute for use with foreign key relationships, to specify the behavior if the related foreign key object is deleted. Can you use the same attribute with a `OneToOneField`?

Comment: This is very easy to test. Why don't you create a simple app and find out?

Comment: Not really sure how to test, literally started django 2 hours ago - migrating a cakephp webapp to use django..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield):

> `OneToOneField` accepts all of the extra arguments accepted by `ForeignKey`.

So yes, `on_delete` should work as you expect.

(If you're curious you can look at [the implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f233bf47dde1d481108142c8d6b4bb3b3d8c6d08/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L1947). You'll see that `OneToOneField` is a small subclass of `ForeignKey` that basically just forces `unique` to be `True`.)